# React Native - Keyboard avoiding not working if ScrollView is not at the top of the screen

Tags: react-native

```
<View>
    <View style = {{height : X}}></View>
    <ScrollView>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView>
            <View style = {{height : 350}}></View>
            <TextInput/>
            <View style = {{height : 500}}></View>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </ScrollView>
</View>
```

When I tap on the `TextInput`, it is scrolled upward but stop at the position of below where it is supposed to be as much as X, which means it is still hidden under the keyboard.

Actually the problem is not about KeyboardAvoidingView because it also happens without the use of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
render() {
    var a = [];
    for(var i =1; i< 100; i++) a.push(i);
    return (
        <View>
            <Button title = 'Scroll' onPress = {() => this.refs.scroll.scrollTo({x: 0, y: 0, animated: true})}/>
            <ScrollView ref = 'scroll'>{a.map((item, index) => (<TextInput style = {{height : 10 + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) * 5)}}
                placeholder = {item + ''}
                onFocus = {() => {
                    this.refs.scroll.scrollTo({x : 0, y : this.y[index], animated : true});
                }}
                onLayout = {event => {
                    this.y[index] = event.nativeEvent.layout.y;
                }}
            />))}</ScrollView>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Using this solution, there are 2 drawbacks exist which raise other problems require solutions

- Not applicable in case the `TextInput` is inside a `FlatList` or perhaps certain components which contain `TextInput` indirectly. In this case, `event.nativeEvent.layout.y` will always return 0. No problem for multilevel `ScrollView`. Temporarily the solution is to avoid placing the `TextInput` inside a prop component
- The `TextInput`'s offset is relative to wrapper component if it's not the `ScrollView`. Scroll distance must be the summation of `TextInput`'s offset and wrapper's offset if the wrapper is not at the top of ScrollView. Since a parent's post-layout data cannot be passed to a child directly via prop before it is rendered, the `TextInput` must get the wrapper's offset in it's `onFocus` handler
- Default buggy keyboard avoiding sometimes take action after `onFocus`, cancelling `onFocus`'s effect. The temporary solution is to use `setTimeout` to delay `onFocus` action for at least 200 milliseconds

Answer (score 4):

This is what I did it to resolve this issue

```
<KeyboardAvoiding behavior={'padding'} keyboardVerticalOffset={64} style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">
            <View style = {{height : 350}}></View>
            <TextInput/>
            <View style = {{height : 500}}></View>
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      </KeyboardAvoiding>

container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
  }
```

and this is the KeyboardAvoiding class

```
import React from 'react'
import { Platform, KeyboardAvoidingView as ReactNativeKeyboardAvoidingView } from 'react-native'

class KeyboardAvoidingView extends React.Component {
  render() {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      return (
        <ReactNativeKeyboardAvoidingView behavior={'padding'} {...this.props}>
          {this.props.children}
        </ReactNativeKeyboardAvoidingView>
      )
    }

    return this.props.children
  }
}

KeyboardAvoidingView.propTypes = {
  children: React.PropTypes.element,
}

module.exports = KeyboardAvoidingView
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: am I correct to say this line (behavior={'padding'} keyboardVerticalOffset={64}) is the key point for your answer?

Comment: Yes and also the hierarchy of components within render(), did it work?

Comment: If I put a `View` with some height before the `ScrollView`, then on keyboard shown, is the `TextInput` appears above the keyboard?

Comment: Yes it should be above the keyboard.

Comment: no it's not working. instead, it's freezes the scrolling

Comment: `KeyboardAvoidingView` inside `ScrollView` also not working

Comment: `<View>
    <View style = {{height : 50}}></View>
    <ScrollView>
     <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior = 'padding' keyboardVerticalOffset = {64} style = {{flex : 1, alignItems : 'center'}}>
      <View style = {{height : 350}}></View>
      <TextInput autoCorrect = {false}/>
      <View style = {{height : 500}}></View>
     </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </ScrollView>
   </View>`

Comment: what do you want to achieve with this code, I am confused?

Comment: look closely. it is the simplified version of your code. i just swap between `ScrollView` and `KeyboardAvoidingView`. neither is working

Comment: sorry sir. just to clarify. did you understand my question? if not. I'm ready to explain it a little more

Comment: yes please do explain a bit more, I think your question has nothing to do with KeyboardAvoidingView which you updated.

Comment: anyway. thank you sir for your answer and all your efforts to help me. very much appreciate it

Comment: keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always" was my solution